# Date and time dialog to start from current date and time

Tags: date, datetimepicker

I am using date and time dialogs to get current date and time. But my problem is that i want to restrict my date picker to start from current date and secondly my time picker is displaying in 24 Hours format, i want to display it like: 2:00 pm for example. My code is given below, please help me to figure it out how to do it.

```
public void showTime(){
          new TimePickerDialog(VirtualBodyGuardActivity.this,
                  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                      @Override public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, 
                              int h, int min) {


                          cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
                          cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                          cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                          sendDate = cal.getTime();
                          SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
   public void showTime(){
          new TimePickerDialog(VirtualBodyGuardActivity.this,
                  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                      @Override public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, 
                              int h, int min) {


                          cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
                          cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                          cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                          sendDate = cal.getTime();
                          SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "EE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
                          mEdtTimePicker.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(sendDate).toString());
                      }
                  }, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                      cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

    }
    public void showDateTime(){
        Date value = new Date();

        cal.setTime(value);
        new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, 
                        int y, int m, int d) {

                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
                    showTime();
                    // now show the time picker
                 }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

    }                                   "EE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
                     mFormatter.parse(mDateSelected);
                          ;

                          mEdtTimePicker.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(sendDate).toString());
                      }
                  }, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                      cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

    }
    public void showDateTime(){
        Date value = new Date();

        cal.setTime(value);
        new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, 
                        int y, int m, int d) {

                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
                    showTime();
                    // now show the time picker
                 }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

    }
```